# position of new windows after opening

Tags: c#, winforms, window

I try to open new window in C# (WinForms) in same position each time.
Try to use this code:

```
private void Notification_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds; //get resolution of screen
    int x = screenSize.Height -115-30; //x coordinate = resolution of screen - window Height - 30 (for taskbar)
    int y = screenSize.Width - 345; //y coordinate = resolution of screen - window Weight
    this.SetDisplayRectLocation(x, y); //new coordinates for form
}
```

properties of windows StartPosition =Manual

but as result - have that always my  window open in the upper left corner.

try to put different value for x and y - result the same.

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: why don't you just set the `this.Left` and `this.Top` values?

Comment: Why your `x = Height` and `y = Width` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this helps

```
 int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Top;
 int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Left;
 this.Location = new Point(x, y);
```

Comment: `Rectangle screenSize = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;
            int x = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Right - this.Right;
            int y = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Bottom - this.Bottom;
            this.Location = new Point(x,y);` - ok

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
this.Left
this.Top
```

properties of the form

`this.SetDisplayRectLocation` is for setting the view location within a scrollable form:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.setdisplayrectlocation.aspx

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
this.Location=new Point(x,y);
```